# How to completely bring to front a WinForm when activated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two dialogs, `FormA` and `FormB`. I use the following code to show (modeless) `FormB`. The code is a button click executed from `FormA`.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormB fB = new FormB();
        fB.Show(this); // FormA is the owner of FormB
    }
```

The problem is that when `FormB` is over `FormA` on the screen, if I click `FormA`, it is activated, but not brought to front. Actually FormB is always over FormA

[image: Forms]

Do you know why, and how to change this behavior, without remove the owner property?

**NOTE:** This is a simplification of my problem. In the real problem, FormA is a Windows Explorer window, and FormB is a managed WinForm, but the behavior is the same. If I do not pass the IWin32Window to `Show()`, it works fine, but If I close A, B is not closed and it does not respond to events (see the following [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000532/close-child-dialogs-when-closing-the-parent)).

Comment: So your *real* problem is that your dialogs are not modal.  Fix that first, the rest follows.

Comment: @Hans: I DO want the dialogs to be modeless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do this without removing the owner property.

**From Documentation:**
Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx

For your specific problem why do you not listen for the Close Event and then explicitly close your own form?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property to true.

Comment: Your child form is always over the parent form. Even with TopMost.

Comment: @Skomski: Sorry, this was for ARZ. Deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A hack is to set WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized in the OnDeactivate method of FormB (orverride it).

```
  protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
  {
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  }
```

I don't know if that's what you would like.

Comment: But then Form2 is not over Form1. He can also automatic move Form1 etc but that's not want he want.

Comment: That's what he said - Form1 must be brought in front, so the only way I could think of was to minimise the Form2 in his given scenario. Also I put a disclaimer at the end of my answer :)