# How to show modeless owned dialog in .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to show a modeless dialog in **.NET 1.1**. The following code works in .NET 2.0 or higher:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

private void ShowModelessOwnedDialog()
{
   IntPtr wHnd = GetActiveWindow();
   NativeWindow parent = NativeWindow.FromHandle(wHnd);
   MyForm f = new MyForm();
   f.Show(parent);
}
```

The call `Show(IWin32Window)` was [introduced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) in .NET 2.0. Do you know how to trick this code to work in **.NET 1.1**? Maybe any unmanaged call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to assign an owner to a managed form in .NET 1.1. I extracted the following code from @Dave Markle answer and the `Show(IWin32Window)` implemantation of .NET 2.0.

```
    private void AssignOwner()
    {
        AssignOwner(this, GetActiveWindow());
    }

    private void AssignOwner(Form f, IntPtr ownerHandle)
    {
        if (ownerHandle == IntPtr.Zero) return;

        NativeWindow parent = NativeWindow.FromHandle(ownerHandle);

        GetWindowLong(new HandleRef(f, f.Handle), -8);
        SetWindowLong(new HandleRef(f, f.Handle), -8, new HandleRef(parent, ownerHandle));
    }

    public static IntPtr GetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            return GetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex);
        }
        return GetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex);
    }

    public static IntPtr SetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, HandleRef dwNewLong)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            return SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        }
        return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongPtr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, HandleRef dwNewLong);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, HandleRef dwNewLong);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18318) is an article from way back in 1999, showing how you call [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to accomplish this.  My condolences to you for having to use .NET version 1.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx#owned_windows) that after creating the window ownership cannot be transferred.
Because creating the window occurs in `Form` constructor, this poses a problem for you.

However Raymond Chen [says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx):

> Ownership is a concept that relates top-level windows. A top-level window can optionally have an owner, which is also specified when you call `CreateWindowEx`, and **which you can change by a complicated mechanism described in my talk**.

I assume the talk in question is [from PDC 05](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/scobleizer/Raymond-Chen-PDC-05-Talk-Five-Things-Every-Win32-Programmer-Needs-to-Know/) but I can't be certain.

Did you give [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a try?

```
static extern void SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Comment: This is a simplified problem, the original, and the reason I need to show a modeless (but owned) dialog one is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000532/close-child-dialogs-when-closing-the-parent

Comment: Would you try to put a bounty on it? This is in itself a very interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [MessageBox.Show overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335416%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) taking and IWin32Window in .net 1.1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335416(v=VS.71).aspx

```
public static DialogResult Show(
 IWin32Window owner,
 string text,
 string caption,
 MessageBoxButtons buttons,
 MessageBoxIcon icon,
 MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton
);
```

And this and example of getting an IWin2Window [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure that this is a correct answer? I don't need to show a messagebox. I need to show MyDialog, not modal, but owned.